# Angular Js ng-repeat with custom directive templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, custom-directive

I'm using a custom directive in angular js with template url the link to code is [here](https://github.com/Rishabh-Ahuja/angularCustomDirectiveNgRepeat). The Problem is ngRpeat is not working with template url if I pass ngRepeat to the element then it does not work but if I pass in the template itself it works.

Comment: add fiddle with issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

Following is the code you've written in main.html

```
<search-results customers-d ="customers" ng-repeat="CM in customersD></search-results>
```

Following is the directive searchResults you've written:

```
myApp.directive('searchResults', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'directives/search.html',
        scope: {
            customersD: '=',
        }
    }
});
```

Following is the main controller you've written:

```
myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log) {
    $scope.customers = [{ name:'Rishabh'},{name:'Krishna'}]
}]);
```

And search.html is as follows:

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"> hi </h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">{{CM.name}}</p>
</a>
```

**Now things you are doing wrong:**

1. Missing closing quote in ng-repeat of main.html
2. Trying to access customersD in main.html, while no array named customersD is defined in $scope of mainController.
3. Trying to access CM in search.html (which is template of isolated scope directive). You can only have customersD in search.html

I think your understanding of scopes is not correct. It would be good if you read enough before asking questions here. :)

**Previous Answer:**
You are missing closing quote in ng-repeat and using wrong variables
Do as follows :

```
<search-results customers-d ="CM" ng-repeat="CM in customers"></search-results>
```

Comment: added that quote and ur variable still not showing name and aslo plz explain the reasons to change variable

Comment: Hey Pranav Thanks For Your Reply ! Your Second Point Says Trying to access customersD in main.html, while no array named customersD is defined in $scope of mainController. But Thats why I have defined customersD which is accessing customers object

Comment: `customers-d ="customers"` passes `customers` object to directive and can be accessed in directive using `customersD` but the array you are trying to ng-repeat is `customersD` which is not present in scope of mainController.
So no loop is executed and nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

main.html

```
<div class="list-group">
    <search-results customers-d ="customers" ng-repeat="CM in customers"></search-results>
</div>
```

Directive changes in app.js

```
myApp.directive('searchResults', function () {
return {
    restrict : "AE",
    templateUrl: 'directives/search.html'
}
});
```